# MongoDb nested aggregations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation

I'm trying to aggregate 3 mongodb table

**Gig**

```
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "gig1", ticket: objectId1 }
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "gig2", ticket: objectId2 }
```

**Ticket**

```
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "ticket1", agent: objectId1 }
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "ticket2", agent: objectId2 }
```

**Agent**

```
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "agent1" }
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "agent2" }
```

I did build a pipeline through Studio 3T and it was working correctly and returning results
but when trying to execute through the code it did return 0 results

Here's the pipeline code:

```
db.getCollection("gigs").aggregate(
    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $lookup: // Equality Match
            {
                                from: 'Tickets',
                                localField: 'ticket',
                                foreignField: '_id',
                                as: 'ticket',
                            
            }
        },
        // Stage 2
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$ticket",
            }
        },
        // Stage 3
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$ticket.agent",
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $match: {
                                'ticket.agent': {
                                    $exists: true,
                                }
                            }
        },
    ]
);
```

and when trying to execute the same pipeline through the code it didn't return any results
here's my code:

```
Gigs.aggregate()
                .lookup({
                    from: 'Tickets',
                    localField: 'ticket',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'ticket',
                })
                .unwind('$ticket')
                .unwind('$ticket.agent')
                .match({
                    'ticket.agent': {
                        $exists: true,
                    },
                });
```

Comment: What kind of library are you using? i've never seen this Mongo syntax in nodejs before

Comment: mongoose library

Comment: Do you have a link to where you found this syntax? also just try to write `Gigs.aggregate([ ... ])` instead of `db.getCollection("gigs").aggregate([...])`

Comment: I think its aggregation pipeline builder: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html

Comment: @M1M6 i have implemented in code, its working for me, you can check properly in other scenarios console properly model and collection name in code.

Comment: @turivishal Can you please share with me an example

Comment: @M1M6 I have implemented the same thing its working, how can show you? can you debug with try catch block and search the exact problem.

Comment: @M1M6 might be this will take bit time to return data, so you have to put it in `async` function and put await before `await Gigs.aggregate()`